# Which AA Admirals' Club location at DFW is most comfortable?

Tags: american-airlines, lounges, dfw

I'm travelling to [DFW](http://www.dfwairport.com) soon, where I'll be on layover for about 3-4 hours. I'll be arriving into terminal D (international arrivals). I'm not sure what terminal I'm departing from, but I know they are all fairly easy to access and transit between airside. If I have plenty of time to choose, which [American Airlines Admirals' Club](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/airportAmenities/AdmiralsClub.jsp?anchorLocation=DirectURL&title=admiralsclub) should I use? (there is one in each of terminals A, B, C, and D). Criteria I'd normally decide on include:

- How cramped/spacious/quiet they are.
- Selection of free food and drink.
- Views out of the window.
- Quality of showers.

(I am AA Emerald travelling internationally; I noticed there are also BA and Qantas lounges in terminal D; am I eligible to use them, and are they nicer?).

Comment: "Most comfortable" is a bit subjective.. right?

Comment: It may or may not be subjective depending on how major clear obvious the differences are. So no need to jump the gun on that. But it would help if Andrew specified what he prefers in a lounge.

Comment: I've tried to make the criteria more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are planning to use the BA or Qantas lounges, I would suggest you bring a copy of the OneWorld lounge access rules with you. The BA lounge at least has contract staff doing the sign-in, and they tend not to be that familiar with the more unusual cases.

The [BAEC FlyerTalk lounge details sticky has a good comparison of the BA and AA lounges](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1425236-ba-lounge-database-north-america.html#post19996983) (scroll down to DFW). The BA lounge is a lot smaller, but it has free food, free drinks and champagne on request. The AA D lounge has a very small range of free drinks (though BAEC guests get drinks vouchers for more, but I think AA ones don't), and no free food. The AA lounge in D is much larger, has better views over the airport, and is open longer.

I believe that the AA lounge in terminal D is the largest and nicest, but I'm told the ones in other terminals aren't that bad, though suffer from a similar lack of free food / limited free drinks. The BA lounge and AA in D both have showers, though I've not tried either. I'm not sure about the other AA clubs, but I'd guess the D one would get the most use for that.

Assuming you're flying into DFW in the afternoon, I'd suggest you head first to the BA or Qantas lounge. Get some food there, and sample the champagne. Nearer the time of your connecting flight, drift over to that terminal, and have a last drink + use of wifi in the AA lounge near your gate. I would advise against waiting in D until the last minute, then dashing from a D lounge to a different terminal gate, as there can be a wait for trains + long walks and it's not much fun to have to run...

If you don't mind wading through the odd off-topic bit, FlyerTalk often has good comparisons. See posts like [this](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/american-aadvantage/1461427-dfw-admirals-club-club-dfw.html) or [this](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/oneworld/1435167-splitting-hairs-qf-aa-lounge-dfw-terminal-d.html) or [this](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/american-aadvantage/590867-dfw-dallas-fort-worth-ba-executive-club-contract-lounge-consolidated.html) for recent discussions on them.

Oh, and there's also a Priority Pass lounge in Terminal D, next door to the BA one. It has a few snacks, an average selection of free drinks (which did include a very nice local beer!), dreadful wifi but a few different areas to sit in. Probably not that relevant for you, but might be suitable for others!

Comment: Just a gentle reminder: [this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100) `(-;`

Comment: @hippietrail For 3 near identical links with the same description, it seemed the best way to handle it. If you can think of a cleaner way to link to them, please edit away! :)

Comment: Sometimes I'm better at diagnosing than at curing `\-:`